# $_POST of a form showing null

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using javascript and trying to call another function from  a function with passing arguments in $_POST variable of php ! I cant figure Why am I getting null every time.

Here's the code for the form in javascript

```
" To " +
        "<select name='to'>"; 
        //document.write(arr.length); 
        for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
        if(arr[i])
        txt_bottom += "<option  value='" + arr[i] + "'>" + arr[i] + "</option>";    
        }
        txt_bottom+= "</select> <br> <br>" +


"Input : <input type='text' name='input_value' />
 <input type='submit' value='Evaluate'
 onclick=\"calculate_mesurement('<?php echo isset($_POST["from"])?$_POST["from"]:"nothing"?>', '<?php echo isset($_POST["to"])?>')\"/> <br><br>" +
```

To make the code clear this is just informative that `calculate_measurement` accepts two arguments

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Where is your `<form>` tag ???

Comment: those are all the part of the code but i have only posted the concerned one

Comment: don't mix javascript and server side language. it is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to run `calculate_mesurement` using the values the user just entered into `from` and `to`? `$_POST` isn't set until the form is submitted, you have to use Javascript to get form values prior to submitting.

```
onclick="calculate_mesurement(document.getElementsByName('from')[0].value, document.getElementsByName('to')[0].value)"
```